# How to save dropdown values in database in asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

When I select category from dropdown it is not saving in database. In database it is showing 101 for all values

MY view.cshtml is

```
<h4>RecStock</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Category, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.DropDownList("Category",null, new { @class = "form-control" } )
                </div>
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Category, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
    </div>
```

My Controller is

```
 public ActionResult Create()
    {
        ViewBag.Category = new SelectList(db.ProductDetails, "id", "Category");
        return View();
    }


    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Category,ProductName,ReceiveQty,Date")] RecStock recStock)
    {

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.RecStocks.Add(recStock);
            ViewBag.Category = new SelectList(db.ProductDetails, "id", "Category", recStock.id);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(recStock);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be using "DropDownListFor" and assign the selected dropdown value to the corresponding model property, like this:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.MyModelProperty, new SelectList(Model.ListOfStuff, "ListOfStuffId", "ListOfStuffName"), string.Empty, new {@class = "form-control", id = "myList"})
```

Comment: While this is a far better syntax, it does not explain OP's issue - and both methods ultimately call the same code internally (and did you seriously update that question)

Comment: @StephenMuecke why doesn't it? His version doesn't have the "for", therefore it doesn't know which model property to assign the value to. Also, I didn't update the question, unless I'm missing something in that comment)

Comment: Sorry, that was supposed to upvote (not update). OP's code might be awful practice but it will still bind correctly to a property named `Category` (assuming its an `int`). The question cannot be answered - we have no idea what OP's model or data is.